# jQuery UI Theme that aligns perfectly with the admin UI

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Anyone knows a theme that's not only close (like "smoothness"), but *really* aligns with the look and feel of the admin UI?

Comment: Related trac ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18909

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Please add that as an answer, as there won't come a better one, so I can close it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related trac ticket: [Bundled jQuery UI should have CSS](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18909)